# Why is there a parse error in my android layout XML?

Tags: android, layout, ads

My activity_main.xml layout file indicates an error: error parsing XML: unbound prefix.  No idea why - it seems related to the AdView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


<-- ERROR HERE - error parsing XML: unbound prefix -->
  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
      android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxx/xxxxxx"
                         ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"/>    

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to define the `ads` prefix for the custom attributes (`adSize` & `adUnitId`).

Add to the `LinearLayout` container:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

More details [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start#step_1_create_fragment_adxml).

Comment: i was actually using this previously with no success. but yours works.  no idea where this came from xmlns:googleads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Comment: @glutz: that would work just fine too, but you'd have to use the `googleads` prefix with the attributes in that case; i.e. `googleads:adSize`. As a matter of fact, you can give it any name you like, as long as you're consistent.

Comment: @glutz: Please don't forget to accept the answer so that others can potentially benefit from it too!

Answer (score 0):

You may have forgotten to add this

```
 xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Have you also included the right library?